# Mongodb - search in nested document without knowing keys

Tags: python, database, mongodb, search, pymongo

*I have trouble searching documents (in **pymongo**)*

**Problem:**

**I can** search documents from mongodb that has flat or nested structure with the condition that I know the keys of the structure:

example:

```
document = {
      'known_key1': <value>,
      'known_key2': {
           'known_key3': <value>
                    }
            }
```

However **I cannot** search documents of this type(below). I want to search documents based on **known_key_1,2,3,4**, without knowing **unknown_key1,2**

```
document = {
           'known_key1': <value>,
           'known_key2': {
                   'unknown_key1': {
                          'unknown_key2': {
                                'known_key3':<value>,
                                'known_key4':<value>
                                           }
                                    }
                         }
           }
```

I looked at documentation but didnt find anything. Is it even possible? thanks in advance

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197652/how-to-find-mongodb-field-name-at-arbitrary-depth

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want clearly, first try to find info about pymongo/mongodb complex nested query, something like this must be in the documentation, I worked with this before but I can't find it at the moment.

Check this: [nested queries in pymongo using collection.find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515195/nested-queries-in-pymongo-using-collection-find)

also you can just leave this, and create for example two loops to go through them:

```
for u_k1 in document[known_key2]:
    for u_k2 in document[known_key2][u_k1]:
        print([known_key2][u_k1][u_k2][known_key3])
        print([known_key2][u_k1][u_k2][known_key4])
```

Comment: As I said, I can search in nested documents with known keys, but I need to make query that will get deep in nested structured without knowing keys

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-query-nested-json-objects-in-mongodb ?

Comment: i dont know the keys, your answer count with the fact that you know the keys