# How to query nested document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have document with nested document `reviews`:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("53a5753937c2f0ef6dcd9006"),
        "product" : "Super Duper-o-phonic",
        "price" : 11000000000,
        "reviews" : [
                {
                        "user" : "fred",
                        "comment" : "Great!",
                        "rating" : 5
                },
                {
                        "user" : "Tom",
                        "comment" : "Great again!",
                        "rating" : 5
                },
                {
                        "user" : "Tom",
                        "comment" : "I agree with fred somewhat",
                        "rating" : 4
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to find only those `reviews` whose rating is 5.

Final query should select `product` `price` and two documents  from `reviews` whose `rating` is 5.

The last query I tried is :

```
db.testData.find({'reviews':{$elemMatch:{'rating':{$gte:5}}}}).pretty()
```

It's strange but it doesn't work.

How to do this in mongodb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want a *single* sub-doc from `reviews` whose `rating` is 5, you can use the [`$` positional projection operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) to include the first element of `reviews` that matches your query:

```javascript
db.test.find({'reviews.rating': 5}, {product: 1, price: 1, 'reviews.$': 1})
```

If you want *all* `reviews` elements with a `rating` of 5 (instead of just the first) you can use `aggregate` instead of `find`:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    // Only include docs with at least one 5 rating review
    {$match: {'reviews.rating': 5}}, 
    // Duplicate the docs, one per reviews element
    {$unwind: '$reviews'}, 
    // Only include the ones where rating = 5
    {$match: {'reviews.rating': 5}}, 
    // Only include the following fields in the output
    {$project: {product: 1, price: 1, reviews: 1}}])
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work if I select two documents from `reviews` with rating 5. because `reviews.$` ensures that only the first matching document is included in result.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Use the `aggregate` approach if you want to include all rating 5 reviews instead of just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look up here: [MongoDB - how to query for a nested item inside a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885044/mongodb-how-to-query-for-a-nested-item-inside-a-collection)

Just in case you thought about this:
If you try to accomplish this with `$elemMatch`it will jsut return the first matching review.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: I tried $elemMatch and it doesn't work. Can you post a query?